# 403 error - trying to work with mailchimp API

Tags: node.js

I am working on a small project with mailchimp API where the user will be able to sign up for the newsletter and the owner (in this case me) will see all new users details to use for sending the newsletters. Everything worked ok until I realised I need to hide my API KEY. So I created a new .env file and put the API_KEY variable storing my api key and then I created a variable in the app.js file   var api_key = process.env.API_KEY;

I receive an error (403). I would appreciate some help as everything was working ok until I added .env file.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post("/failure", function(req, res){
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
  console.log("server is running on port 3000");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

  var firstname = req.body.name;
  var lastname = req.body.lastname;
  var email = req.body.email;

  var data ={
    members: [{
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: firstname,
        LNAME: lastname
      }
    }]
  }

  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(jsonData);
  var api_key = process.env.API_KEY;

  var options = {
    url: "https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/e1bb5cc754",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "paula1 "+api_key
    },
    body: jsonData
  };


  request(options, function(error, response, body){
    if (error) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
    }else {
      if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
      }else {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        res.send("there was an error with signing up, please try again")
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you've correctly used environment variable. Can you please show to full error logs. ? Just print error along with the status code and you'll get it.

Comment: the variable is simply: API_KEY = ************************; and then the error says "there was an error with signing up, please try again" :(

Comment: What this api actually do ? 
Is it like creating some profile or what ?

Comment: by filling the form the user will be able to sign up for the mailchimp newsletter. I will update the question and post a picture where you can see how it looks from the owner perspective.